graphql api fetching issue in next js getting ( Error: React functionality 'useContext' is not available in this environment. )
I have created a next js 14.2.3 app & I have graphql api end point(** which I replaced with localhost for stackOverflow )and I am using "@apollo/client":"^3.10.3", "graphql":"^16.8.1", for fetching data. I have created a product page path "pages/products".
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { initializeApollo } from "../lib/apollo-client";

const PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Products {
    products(first: 10, channel: "default-channel") {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

function Products() {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(PRODUCTS_QUERY, {
    client: apolloClient,
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <ul>
        {data &&
          data.products.edges.map(({ node }) => (
            <li key={node.id}>{node.name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;


I have created a apollo-client,js file
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

let apolloClient;

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql/",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient();

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial
  state;
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState);
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _apolloClient;
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;

  return _apolloClient;
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState]);
  return store;
}


so when I am routing http://localhost:3000/pages/products
getting error - 

I think this is because <Products /> component currently rendered as server component. And Contexts is not avaliable for server components.
There are two ways to fix it:

is to make this component client by adding "use client" on top of pages/products.

Rewrite the component to use apollo client directly without relying on useQuery hook. Here is a good artlice explaining how to do it.


Crud example:
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { initializeApollo } from "../lib/apollo-client";

const PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Products {
    products(first: 10, channel: "default-channel") {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

async function Products() {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: PRODUCTS_QUERY,
    context: {},
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <ul>
        {data?.products?.edges?.map(({ node }) => (
          <li key={node.id}>{node.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Products;


Recently, I also came across with this error. I tried the first fix given by laroslav Sobolev but though I used "use client" on the top of the page, it was of no use, then I got to know the real reason of this error which was that the provider of @apollo/client needs to be in the client environment.
Here is how to set up the Provider in client environment.
First make a Provider.tsx file in the root or GraphQL folder.
provider.tsx
"use client";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

export const Provider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:5050/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

And now put this provider in the layout.tsx
layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { Provider } from "@/graphql/provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

